# Ajax and javascript not work for all clicks

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

i have problem when i click on comment button just the first comment button work even thought i have a  for loob where each post has a comment button:

```
  <textarea id="comment"></textarea>
  <button class="btn btn-success" id="addComment">comment</button>
```

this the javascript code :

```
 $('#addComment').on('click', function () {

    postId = event.target.parentNode.childNodes[1].dataset['postid'];
    commentbody=event.target.parentNode.childNodes[2];
    userId=event.target.parentNode.childNodes[2];

    $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: addComment,
            data: {comment: $('#comment').val(), postId: postId, _token: token,userId:}
        })
        .done(function (msg) {
         $(commentbody).text('');   
        alert('done');

        });
});`
```

i want to know how to let the javascript function work through the loop

Comment: `event` is undefined... And where is the `for` loop you're talking about?

Comment: I see no for loop and look at the console in your browser. I am sure there is an error.

Comment: yes there is for loop but i couldnot include it  here in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're using id selectors which are unique, apptempt to use class selectors.

https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/
$('#addComment') => will query dom for element with ID addComment

https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/
$('.addComment') => will query dom for elements with class addComment

Example:

```
  <textarea class="comment"></textarea>
  <button class="btn btn-success addComment">comment</button> 

\\js



$('.addComment').on('click', function (event) {
    postId = event.target.parentNode.childNodes[1].dataset['postid'];
    commentbody=event.target.parentNode.childNodes[2];
    userId=event.target.parentNode.childNodes[2];
    var comment: $(event.target).find(".comment").val(); 

$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: addComment,
    data: {comment: comment,
```

....

Comment: i still have  aproblem , that when i want to save the comment it just save me the first post comment if i try to add to second post it give error 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

Answer (score 0):

> you should not have two element with same id

remove id and add "addComment" class to all button

> here is working code

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <textarea class="comment"></textarea>
  <button class="btn btn-success addComment">comment</button>
  <textarea class="comment"></textarea>
  <button class="btn btn-success addComment">comment</button>
  <textarea class="comment"></textarea>
  <button class="btn btn-success addComment">comment</button>

  </body>
</html>

$('.addComment').on('click', function (event) {

   /*  postId = event.target.parentNode.childNodes[1].dataset['postid'];
    commentbody=event.target.parentNode.childNodes[2];
    userId=event.target.parentNode.childNodes[2]; */

    $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '',
            data: {comment: $('.comment').val(), postId: "test", _token: "test",userId:"test"}
        })
        .done(function (msg) {
            /* $(commentbody).text(''); */   
            alert('done');
        });
});
```